# Can't parse JSON from data in connectionDidFinishLoading – Maybe it's too much data?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, nsurlconnection, sbjson

I'm sending out a request to an external API and parsing a response with the [SBJson parser](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/). However, I suspect the response is so long, it is somehow getting jumbled.

In my mainviewcontroller.h file I set     `NSMutableData *receivedData;` so that I can use it in the connection methods in the mainviewcontroller.m file.

However, after the connection finishes loading, I execute the following:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *allData = [dataString JSONValue];
}
```

However, I get a bunch of errors saying that the JSON is not properly formatted. So, when I look at the JSON, its very long – but here and there, there are problems... for example, the "updated_at" below.

```
  {
            "id": 7844333,
            "position": 3,
            "content": "Cell height is off by 5 pixels",
            "created_at": "2012-06-04T20:31:30-05:00",
            "updated_at": "2ator": {
                "id": 98258,
                "name": "Brian"
            }
```

What I think happened above is that updated at has a value of "2012-06...etc" and the next key-value item would be creator : { id, name } but it somehow got jumbled into updated at.

Anyone having a similar problem? I don't think the problem is with the JSONValue because I nslog out the dataString before it gets parsed, and thats where I find the JSON errors.

What I mean by that is that `NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` is just a long string, but has bad JSON in it because it is jumbled.

Comment: What do you see if you just go to the URL in a browser? (Just making 100% sure it's not a problem with the server!)

Comment: Otherwise, can you add the code where you deal with received data in your NSURLConnection delegate? Can you NSLog each bit of data you receive to check it as it arrives?

Comment: The browser shows the correct JSON data. It's when I try to build the receivedData by appending one after one, it jumbles it. Ill add that code above.

Comment: Are you getting two URLs at the same time - if so you might be accidentally using the same `receivedData` for both NSURLConnections?

Comment: Yeah that ended up being the problem. receivedData was being used all the various connections that I was sending out (simultaneously) and was being appended incorrectly. If you want to submit it as answer below (to gain the rep), I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using receivedData by more than one connection at once?

:)

Answer (score -1):

I think your json is wrong. For checking that just  put json file into the :
http://jsonlint.com/

If it is valid then:

Import the SBJSON framework classes into your project.And try the following code:

```
 SBJSON *parser=[[SBJSON alloc]init];

NSDictionary * dictionary = [parser objectWithString:responseString];
```

this will give you data into dictionary then by using:

```
NSString *firstParseData=[dictionary objectForKey:@"your key"];
```

you can retrieve the data. Hope this will work in your case.

Comment: Yeah I know it's wrong. I ran it through JSONLint and it showed an error at the key/value "updated_at"  But, what I'm saying is that the data given to the parser is bad. I don't understand why receivedData is building a bad JSON string. It gets corrupted.